# ReferenceError: serverTest is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to pass a consol.log() output to a function, but i'm getting an error, i'm trying to fix this for hours but failed to do so. This is actually for travis ci but i'm having a hard time reading through all the documentation.

```
    $ npm test

    > rpoint-pos@0.0.1 test /home/ian/Projects/RPOINT-POS
    > mocha || true

    /home/ian/Projects/RPOINT-POS/app.js:62
    console.log(serverTest);
                ^

    ReferenceError: serverTest is not defined
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/ian/Projects/RPOINT-POS/app.js:62:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:416:28)
    at Server.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1347:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
```

app.js file

```
    //connect to mongodb
    mongoose
      .connect(
        db,
       {   useNewUrlParser: true }
     )
    .then(() => console.log(dbTest))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

     //routes
    app.use("/", require("./routes/web"));
    app.use("/api", require("./routes/api"));

   app.set("port",process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.listen(app.get("port"),function(){
    console.log(serverTest);
    });

   module.exports = {
     serverTest: function() {
       return 'running';
     },
     dbTest: function() {
      return 'connected';
    }
    }
```

and trying to pass those function to test.js file

```
    const assert = require('chai').assert;
    const app = require('../app');

    //Results
    serverTestResult = app.serverTest();
    dbTestResult = app.dbTest();

    describe('App', function(){
      describe('serverTest()', function(done){
        it('sayHello should return server', function(){
         assert.equal(serverTestResult, 'running');
    });

    it('serverTest should return type string', function(){
      assert.typeOf(serverTestResult, 'string');
    });
  });

  describe('dbTest()', function(done){
    it('sayHello should return server', function(){
      assert.equal(dbTestResult, 'connected');
    });

    it('dbTest should return type string', function(){
      assert.typeOf(dbTestResult, 'string');
    });
  });

    });
```

Comment: console.log tries to find it in the global object, there's no field in there indeed. Instead, you may find it in module.exports, so console.log(module.exports.serverTest) should work.

Comment: It's not clear why you are doing this though.

Comment: sorry the app.js and test.js is just a snippet of the whole file